# How to switch off statement logging from a trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger, logging

I just spent ages working out how to record messages from triggers into a log file. And then nearly as long working out where the logs files were being created.

Anyway, I added this line to my trigger:

```
  RAISE LOG 'recentRecordId=<%>', recentRecordId;
```

And then found a logfile with the corresponding information:

```
2019-08-30 16:32:49.721 BST [14060] LOG:  recentRecordId=<1782862109>
```

Great - just what I wanted!

After that was an addition line (not required):

```
2019-08-30 16:32:49.721 BST [14060] CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function parsemess() line 597 at RAISE
```

Followed by another line (also not required) starting with:

```
2019-08-30 16:32:49.721 BST [14060] STATEMENT:  RELEASE _EXEC_SVP_000001DCAC8DC240;SAVEPOINT _EXEC_SVP_000001DCAC8DC240;
```

And continuing with the entire transaction (about 100 INSERTS).

The only data I want or need is on the LOG line, how do I stop logging `CONTEXT` and `STATEMENT`? It's generating vast amount of information and will soon clog my drive.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. You could use another language like PL/Python and write your log entries to a different file using normal Python techniques.